# Boot order on Macbook

Tags: mac, boot, livecd

On a normal PC, one can enter Bios, set HDD as primary boot devices and lock Bios with a password.

Is there any way of preventing a MacBook from being bootable with any pirate live disc medium?

It's not only about data security, but also I don't want Joe Schmoe to overwrite my HDD with e.g. a Linux install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a firmware password and then disable the ability to press <kbd>C</kbd> to boot from CD. See [Setting up firmware password protection in Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1352?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Ah, via a GUI - and only using MacOS. That's so Apple...

Comment: There is also a command line tool: https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=58